# VBA to compare multiple fields on form in ms access to make buttons visible or invisible

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here is the code which is not working:

```vb
If Me.ReasonCode.Value = 1 And Me.Consumed_Time.Value <= Me.Calculat.Value Then
    Me.Command131.Visible = True
    Me.Command132.Visible = True
    Me.Command154.Visible = True
Else
    Me.Command131.Visible = False
    Me.Command132.Visible = False
    Me.Command154.Visible = True
End If

If Me.ReasonCode.Value = 1 And IsNull(Me.Calculat.Value) = True Then
    Me.Command131.Visible = True
    Me.Command132.Visible = True
    Me.Command154.Visible = True
Else
    Me.Command131.Visible = False
    Me.Command132.Visible = False
    Me.Command154.Visible = True
End If

If Me.ReasonCode.Value = 0 And Me.Consumed_Time.Value < Me.MAximumHours.Value Then
    Me.Command131.Visible = True
    Me.Command132.Visible = True
    Me.Command154.Visible = True
Else
    Me.Command131.Visible = False
    Me.Command132.Visible = False
    Me.Command154.Visible = True
End If

If Me.ReasonCode.Value = -1 Then
    Me.Command131.Visible = True
    Me.Command132.Visible = True
    Me.Command154.Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: Have in mind, please, that we don't know what _not working_ means.

Comment: code is not changing the status of buttons to hide or visible on the base of criteria of fields.

Comment: The two first blocks will be overridden by the third and forth.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is running without any compilation errors, then I would guess that the visibility of the command buttons are being set to False/False/True, due to falling into the Else part of the third If/Else block, despite having been set otherwise in one of the previous two If/Else blocks.

You can check if this is the case by setting a breakpoint at the start of the code, and stepping through it to see if this is the case.

I would suggest either nesting the If blocks, or else using Select Case, so that only one set of outcomes can be chosen within the code.